# How can I explain the grammar used in these phrases?

Tags: verbs

1. Art is intended to be appreciated for its...
2. Art came to be seen as...

Are all these verbs just an example of periphrasis or is there something else?

I want to explain this to an English learner, she wants to know why we are using so many verbs. What is the function of each verb there?

Thank you!

Comment: This question is almost unanswerable. So many verbs? There is no way to answer this question unless the people giving answers can compare to the language of your English language learner. What is your language?

Comment: I only see two verbs in each of your examples, which doesn't seem like a lot.  These two verbs combine to make this a compound action, no different from something like "try to make" or "begin to write" -- structures which should exist in almost any language.

Comment: I can't see anything periphrastic here. In the first sentence, the copula is used to form the passive voice of _intend._ That verb takes the passive infinitive of _appreciate,_ which is also formed with the copula. That's just the way the passive voice works in English. I'd explain it like that. As to the question _"Why,"_ we use verbs because that is how we talk about states and actions.